# Save Log to another Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

After some research, I was able to find a script that will log all the changes on my sheet to another sheet called "DO NOT DELETE" but what I cannot find is how to modify this to log the changes to a totally different google workbook not on the same book in a different sheet.

Can someone assist me with this?

I tried following this [Copy Google Spreadsheet Data to another Sheet with Apps Script](https://www.labnol.org/code/20239-copy-google-spreadsheets) but I cannot make it to work.

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  var changelogSheetName = "DO NOT DELETE";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var getColumn = ss.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentSheetName = currentSheet.getName();
//var previousValue = e.oldValue();
  var newValue = cell.getValue();
  var typeChange = "Edit";

// if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change to avoid recursion
 if (ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() !== 15) return;
 var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
 var jnum = ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, -12).getValue()
 var Deadline = ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, -7).getValue()
 if (changelogSheet == null) {

// no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());

Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back

ss.setActiveSheet(currentSheet);    
changelogSheet.getRange('A1:G1').setBackground('#E0E0E0');
changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet", "Cell", "Type", "Old Value", "New Value", "User"]);
changelogSheet.deleteColumns(8,19);
changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 170);
changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(7, 170);
changelogSheet.protect();
 }
var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
/*if (previousValue == null){
typeChange = "Add";
} else if (newValue == "") {
typeChange = "Remove";  
 }*/

 //changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, currentSheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), typeChange, newValue, user, ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, -12).getValue()]);
changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, newValue, user, jnum, Deadline, currentSheetName]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getActiveSpreadsheet()` in the following codeline:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

you could use `open(file)`, `openById(id)` or `openByUrl(url)`

Instead of a simple trigger, use an installable trigger. To do this change the name of the function and follow the instructions of https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.

Summary, you have two alternatives to create installable triggers, 1) using code, 2) using the Google Apps Script UI.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Comment: @Arpee look into "installable triggers"

Comment: As @TheMaster suggested, please check the documentation about [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)